# How can I get Overlay to position graphics according to coordinates?

Tags: graphics

If I draw graphics like this, I get exactly what I need:

```
Graphics[{{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 10, {0, Pi/2}]}, {Red, 
   Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {0, Pi/4}]}}]
```

[image]

But I need to accomplish this task with `Overlay[]`. Here's the code:

```
graphics1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {0, Pi/4}]}];  
graphics2 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 10, {0, Pi/2}]}];  
Overlay[{graphics2, graphics1}]
```

And I get this as output:
[image]

How can I position these graphics according to coordinates?
Thank you for any suggestions or answers.

Comment: Why does it have to be `Overlay` specifically? I think what you are looking for combining multiple `Graphics` objects to one, for which `Overlay` is not the right function.

Comment: Indeed it does not have to be 'Overlay', I didn't think of 'Show'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you use `Show`? It produces the same thing as your first plot:

```
Graphics1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {0, Pi/4}]}];  
graphics2 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 10, {0, Pi/2}]}];  
Show[{graphics2, graphics1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

If you want to add other options, it works as well:

```
Show[{graphics2, graphics1}, PlotRange->{{-10, +10}, {-10, +10}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

You should note that `Show` is order dependent. It draws it in the order that's specified

Answer (score 10):

You can get the desired result using a combination of `ImageSize` in the original image and the `Alignment` option in `Overlay`. (I am not 100% sure why the alignment isn't quite right.)

```
graphics1 = 
 Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {0, Pi/4}]}, ImageSize -> 100]; 
graphics2 = 
 Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 10, {0, Pi/2}]}, ImageSize -> 250]; 
Overlay[{graphics2, graphics1}, Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

The issue here is that overlay will set the sizes of the two images to be the same if it has no information requiring it to do otherwise. So the coordinate systems of the two graphics can differ. This is why `Show` works more seamlessly here: it forces the two graphics to have the same coordinate system.

Comment: I encountered the same problem with     Alignment, but you're right Show is much more appropriate approach than Overlay is for this task, thank you for answer

Comment: You can improve the alignment with `PlotRangePadding -> None` on both graphics